# Locating the largest element in the row of a multi dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'd like to subtract the highest element in this 5x2 matrix, with it's subsequent element, in the other column.

For ex: the highest element right now is 150, whose location is (4,1). I'd like to subtract **150** with **89**, which is it's subsequent element. In the same way if the highest element belonged to the first column, then it should subtract itself from the element in the next column.

Thanks

```
int big=0,lead=0,m,n;

int a[5][2]={140,82,89,150,110,110,112,106,88,90};

for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<2; i++)
    {
        m=j;
        n=i;

        if(a[j][i] > big)

         {
             big = a[j][i];

             if(big == a[j][i])

            {
                 lead = big-a[j][1];
            }

             else

            {
                lead = big-a[1][i];
            }
        }
    }
}

         cout<<big<<"\n"<<lead<<"\n"<<m<<","<<n<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You mean previous, not subsequent?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It will be previous if the highest element belongs to column "2", it will be subsequent if highest element belongs to column "1". 

@alcedine I want to subtract the highest element with its lower counterpart element in the other column.

Comment: I am trying to solve:

https://www.codechef.com/problems/TLG

Using 2D arrays.

Comment: You said what you want, yes. But you must have a specific problem or a specific question that you want help with, and you haven't said what *that* is.

Comment: I have mentioned the link of the question in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you declare the array wrong, i build 2D array as

```
int a[2][5] = {
    {140,82,89,150,110},
    {110,112,106,88,90}
};
```

First, you want to find the largest using big variable (i assume). So

```
int big = 0,n,m;
for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++){
        if(a[x][y] > big){
            big = a[x][y];
            n = x;
            m = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Here you save the biggest and it's coordinate at n and m variable.

After that, you want to subtract it with column - 1 (column + 1 if it is on the first column)

```
if(m == 0){
    big -= a[n][m + 1];
}
else{
    big -= a[n][m - 1];
}
```